# Grails findAllBy() not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-services

I have a table with columns like:
id, externalId, firstname, lastname, email

My Domain:

```
class Employee {

int id
String externalId

static mapping = {
    table "Employee"

    id column: "Id"
    externalId column: "externalId"
    version false
   }    
}
```

My Service:

```
class EmployeeService {

def getEmployee(externalId) {
    def employee = new Employee();

    employee.findAllByExternalId("1234");

    return employee
}
```

Error message in logs say:

```
No signature of method Employee.findAllByExternalId is applicable for argument types (java.lang.String_ values: [1234]
```

My goal is to load an instance of Employee where the externalId matches what I'm giving it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `int id` when you run grails run-app, every domain will automatically create  field `id` & `version` in database, so you must delete this line `int id`

Answer (score 1):

You do know there is a lot wrong with all of that

```
//Create an instance of Employee which currently holds nothing
def employee = new Employee();
//With this empty object of Employ now do findAllByExternalId
    employee.findAllByExternalId("1234");
```

You should be looking up

```
 //This will provide you with the entire employee 
 // domain class any it finds with that externalId. 
 // since it is declared as findAll 
 // the return will naturally be a list even though there may only be 1
 def employees = Employee?.findAllByExternalId("1234")
```

But that is all very long winded what are you trying to do verify it exists or return a list of all employees that have that id ? You refer it to it as getEmployee so I presume you are trying to find one and yet you are looking for an iteration by doing findAll

```
// If you wanted just to check it exists return a boolean like this
//This will return result as a boolean
boolean getEmployee(externalIdd) {
  return  Employee.where { externalId == externalIdd }.exists()
}

//if you wanted purely employee entire object bound to first records
Employee getEmployee(externalIdd) {
  return  Employee.where { externalId == externalIdd }?.find()
}

//if you wanted a list of entire employees like the findAll above
List<Employee> getEmployee(externalIdd) {
  return  Employee.where { externalId == externalIdd }?.findAll()
}
```

are some alternative methods and possible less intense on db depending on what you are trying achieve specifically the boolean vs your current method

Also I called `externalIdd` since when it comes `.where` sometimes having same variable names as what is called causes issues hence the alteration

*E2A* 
As per your comment if you only require id then an id usually is Long hence the strict definition of `Long` you may use `def` - def is more generic and will return anything. I have refined the where to only include property of `id` so if it finds record it will return id then `?:0L` if nothing found return 0`L`For long so return a zero Long you could replace that with `?:null` or not declare it at all.

```
//if you only want to get the id as per comment
    Long getEmployeeId(String externalIdd) {
      return  (Employee.where{externalId == externalIdd}.property('id')?\
      .find()?:0L)
      // Another way close to your findBy but manually declared
      // and only returning id field.
      // return Employee.find{externalId==externalIdd}?.id
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to get the value of the id column by pulling the employee with the externalId value.

Comment: I have left some further comments per block above, they are all methods like yours but defined in a strict manner as to what they expect to return. The very last example provided in edited example should give you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `findAllBy_()` on the Class, not the instance. Also, since you are returning only one `Employee` and not a list, you should use the `findBy_()`. Given that, your service method should look like this:

```
def getEmployee(String externalId){
    return Employee.findByExternalId(exteranlId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a property ended by Id.

```
myInstance.propertyId means get the property "Property" and its Id.
```

And I guess there is a problem during the dynamic finders generation cause this-